# I cannot access a samba shared private folder located on my ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I have setup a samba shared folders on the school's ubuntu server 18.04 as well as users following this guideline https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-samba-on-ubuntu-18-04/

I did this both on my home ubuntu 18.04 desktop and school ubuntu 18.04 server. At home I could access the shared folder with ease using a windows 10 PC on the same network but at school I can only access the public folder that I created. My smb.conf file looks like this for both home and school machines excluding the public folder which I created at school server.

> ```
> [users]
>    path = /samba/users
>    browseable = yes
>    read only = no
>    force create mode = 0660
>    force directory mode = 2770
>    valid users = @sambashare @sadmin
>
> [josh]
>    path = /samba/josh
>    browseable = no
>    force create mode = 0660
>    force directory mode = 2770
>    valid users = josh @sadmin
>
> [piet]
>    path = /samba/piet
>    browseable = no
>    force create mode = 0660
>    force directory mode = 2770
>    valid users = piet @sadmin
> ```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on the server was with the incorrect Time Zone!! I could access all the shared folders after changing to correct TIME ZONE on the server!

I hope this will help someone like me next time.

Thanks.